# Drawing text on an image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write text on an image of a QR-Code but it failed with the following message:

[image]

In my view I have:

```
Font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-lyx/cmmi10.ttf",14)

imageFile = "Qrcode.png"

in1=Image.open(imageFi1e)

# Convert to RGB mode
if im1.mode != "RGB":
    im1.convert("RGB")

# Drawing the text on the picture
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)
draw.text((0, 0),"Marwa",(55,55,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im1)

# Save the image with a new name
im1.save("marked_image.png")
```

Comment: Your code, in images, is useless. Copy and paste the code here as text.

Comment: @Andy - I subjected the image to OCR, fixed the errors that the OCR gave (very minor) and replaced the image with the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image.convert` is not an in-place operation, meaning that it returns the result, rather than changing the owner object (`im1` in this case).

The solution then, is simple. Change

```
im1.convert("RGB")`
```

to

```
im1 = im1.convert("RGB")`
```

Side note: The error itself is caused by passing a three-channel colour tuple to the `text` function when the image was opened in `L` format, normally known as greyscale, which only has a single channel. The `text` function then expects the colour argument to be a single argument between 0 and 255, and treats it as such, resulting in the TypeError.